# Understanding how object initializers work where there are generics involved

Tags: c#, generics, syntax-error

I have created an object that I would like to instantiate by object initialization (or whatever you might call it). Check out this MSDN link [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx) if you are not quite sure what I am talking about. Anyway, the object I have will look something like the following (I'll just post the interface here to simplify things):

```
public interface IEntryPoint<T>
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    IList<ITestItem<T>> Tests { get; set; }
}
```

Then, here is what the interface looks like for the `ITestItem<T>` object:

```
public interface ITestItem<T>
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    T Test { get; set; }
}
```

Then, the actual implementation of the `IEntryPoint<T>` object has a constructor that looks like the following:

```
public EntryPoint(string name, IList<ITestItem<T>> tests)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.tests = tests;
}
```

The implementation of the `ITestItem<T>` constructor is as follows:

```
public TestItem(string name, T test)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.test = test;
}
```

Well, now that you have an idea of what my objects look like I will try to explain my problem. Again, what I am trying to do is to instantiate my `EntryPoint` object, by *object initialization* (see the link above to understand what I mean). I am getting a syntax error when I try to do this, and I just can't understand why. So with that being said, here is what it looks like when I try to instantiate a new `EntryPoint`:

```
ITestItem<int> testItem = new TestItem<int>("My Test", 0);
IEntryPoint<int> entryPoint = new EntryPoint<int>
{
    Name = "My Entry Point",
    Tests = new List<ITestItem<int>>() { testItem }
};
```

Comment: Rather than showing us bits here and there, and then saying you get "a syntax error" without telling us what the error is, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: (It doesn't help that you haven't shown the parameterless `EntryPoint<T>` that you appear to be calling. Maybe that's the problem?)

Comment: @JonSkeet Ahh... That's what I was going for, but fell short. Sorry.

Comment: @JonSkeet I will add that too my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have a constructor with two parameters, now default constructor i.e. parameterless wouldn't be available unless you specify in the type explicitly, so you woudn't be able to use object initializer if parameterless constructor doesn't exists, add a parameterless contructor for `EntryPoint`:

```
public EntryPoint()
{

}
```

For reference, please have a look at [How to: Initialize Objects by Using an Object Initializer (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx)

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I do not have a parameter-less constructor. Only the one that I posted in the code. Let me give this a try, this will probably do it.

Comment: That link that you've just added to your answer... I already have that link in my question (which apparently I didn't read all the way through). But again, thanks.

Comment: Yes, this was my problem. I added the default (parameter-less) constructor, and it fixed my problem.